# Как проверить, является ли один коммит держателем другого коммита?

Tags: git

Представьте себе такую конфигурацию коммитов:
[image: graph commits]

Коммит `B` является предком для коммитов `C` и `D`.

Коммит `B` является **держателем** для коммита `C`. Если удалить коммит `B`, тогда будет удален коммит `C`. А коммит `D` удален не будет, потому он держится еще коммитом `A`.

Но есть ли команда, которая позволит проверить, является ли один коммит **держателем** другого коммита?

Comment: Кормит А является предком С. Наверное вам надо что бы между В и С не было merge-коммитов

Comment: Не соглашусь. Вот например конфигурация https://imgur.com/Zcu2LmX, где между B и C есть merge коммит, но B по прежнему является единственным предком C.

Comment: На картинке https://imgur.com/Zcu2LmX у `С` аж 7 (или 6) предков. А коммит `А` является предком для всех.

Comment: Если я удалю коммит `B`, коммит `C` в результате тоже будет удален. А коммит `D` будет держаться еще за коммит `A`. Я это имею в виду. Мне это надо проверить.

Comment: Похоже, вам нужен mercurial, в котором есть ветки (ветки).

Comment: Насколько я могу понять, на самом деле вас интересует можно ли дойти от A до *X* если удалить B. До D можно, до C нельзя. Так?

Comment: @AlexeyTen да верно. я переписал вопрос, чтобы было понятнее

Comment: Что-то с ходу не придумывается

Comment: Не "держатель", а родитель. Что в вашем понятии - "удалить" коммит из серидины? Какими командами вы это делаете? Почему вы думаете, что коммит C будет удалён?

Comment: 1. что это вообще за выдумка такая — «держатель»? 2. удалить коммит невозможно без переписывания истории, т.е., без измнения взаимосвязей между **всеми** коммитами, являющимися потомками удаляемого коммита.

Comment: @AlexGlebe @aleksandrbarakin я удаляю через filter-branch. я не могу использовать термин родитель/предок, потому что меня могут неправильно понять. в моем понимании держатель - этот такой коммит, который является единственным, кто дежит на себе все ответвление. например если удалить коммит `B`, тогда связь с предками потеряют часть других коммитов (для которых `B` был держателем): https://imgur.com/p3FA1PC

Comment: Может удалиться автоматически коммит, если вы удалите ветку. Эта ветка как раз и является вашим держателем. Всё наоборот. Держатель сверху это **ветка**.

Comment: я удаляю через filter-branch, это и есть переписывание истории